# In the song "Ja is Playing Jazz" (Джа играет джаз), who is Ja?

Tags: meaning, russian-language, song-lyrics, splean

While listening to Splean's last album *Ключ к шифру* (*The Key to the Cipher*) again, I've wondered about a particular line from the song "Джа играет джаз" ("Ja is Playing Jazz"):

> Сегодня Джа играет джаз,
>   А завтра – Родину продаст.

> Today Ja is playing jazz,
>   and tomorrow he'll sell his motherland.
>    <sub>Translation mine.</sub>

It very much seemed like there's some background I was missing, since people don't usually go accusing people of betraying their country in song lyrics for no good reason.

Turned out I was right - [this website](https://reproduktor.net/gruppa-splin/dzha-igraet-dzhaz/), where I also took the lyrics from, claims that "Сегодня он играет джаз, а завтра Родину продаст" ("Today he is playing jazz, and tomorrow he'll sell his motherland.") is a line from a Soviet magazine *Крокодил* (*Crocodile*), which became popular and widely known for some time.

Okay, but who is Ja? [This website](http://teenslang.su/content/%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0) lists "джа" is a slang word for jazz - how is this related to "him" from the magazine? And how does that relate to the rest of the lyrics:

> Сегодня Джа играет джаз,
>   А завтра – Родину продаст.
>   Хотя, кому она нужна?
>   Об этом знает только Джа.
>
> Сегодня Джа играет джаз
>   И это наш последний шанс,
>   Чтобы увидеть старика.
>   Пока не скажет Джа – пока,

My brief summary: Ja is playing jazz; he's an old man; he's going to sell (betray) his country (but who needs it anyway?); and it's their last chance to see "the old man" before he says "goodbye" (presumably dies or runs away).

Is this a reference to some political event I'm surely oblivious to, or just a random reference added in for no reason at all?

Answer (score 9):

Jah is a [god of Rastafari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastafari#Jah_Rastafari_and_Jesus_of_Nazareth).

He is often mentioned is late- / post-soviet era songs. For example "Джа на нашей стороне" by Гражданская Оборона or "[Единственный дом (Джа даст нам всё)](http://aquarium.kroogi.com/ru/content/2051713-Edinstvennyy-Dom-Dzha-dast-Nam-Vsyo.html)" by Boris Grebenshikov.

As some users have doubts about this Jah being Jah Rastafari, here are some examples from other Russian rock songs (all these band are classics of Russian rock).

1. [Гражданская оборона](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grazhdanskaya_Oborona) - Мы в глубокой жопе (literal translation: "We are in deep ass").

Excerpt:

> Благая травка, великий Джа
>
> Полет с девятого этажа
>
> Веселый праздник растафарай
>
> Другое место - терновый рай

Rough translation:

> Sacred weed, great Jah
>
> A jump from the ninth floor
>
> Happy celebration of Rastafari
>
> Other place is thorny paradise

2. [Аквариум](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarium_(band)) - Растаманы из глубинки ("Rastas from the boondocks").

Excerpt:

> Мы знаем, что есть только два пути:
>
> Джа Растафара или война

Rough translation:

> We know there are only two ways
>
> Jah Rastafari or the war

3. [Ночные снайперы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nochnye_Snaipery) - Куба ("Cuba").

Excerpt:

> Мы кубинскими звёздами царапали спину и грудь
>
> И завидовали тем, кто здоровался за руку с Джа

Rough translation:

> We scratсhed our backs and chests with cuban stars
>
> And envied those who shaked hands with Jah.

Comment: [The name "Jah" is older than Rastafarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jah) (if I correctly understand how new Rastafarianism is). However, I'll trust to your understanding of Russian and post-Soviet era Russian music that the reference is Rastafarian.

Comment: @Shokhet Yes, it is indeed older, but I'm sure that's a reference to the Rastafarianism. I can also mention the band [Jah Division](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jah_Division) (page is in Russian) of the same period.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer a bit? E.g. at least provide a translation/transliteration of the Grebenshikov songs you cite, and maybe something to convince the reader (if the translated titles aren't enough) that those do refer to Jah Rastafari rather than some other Jah.

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, I can't provide any reliable sources for my claim, I haven't found any studies on this subject. On the other hand as a Russian living in Russia and listening to this kind of music I am positive about the meaning. If you don't think it's enough feel free to vote down my answer.

Comment: Besides for the things that @Randal'Thor mentioned, do you have any input on the meaning of the rest of the lyrics in "Ja is Playing Jazz"?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I added some examples of other Russian rock songs mentioning Jah.

Comment: It never occurred to me to even look for the latin spelling of the word. Thank you for this. What do you think Ja has to do with jazz, though?

Comment: @DrTyrsa Thank you! That makes the evidence for this answer much clearer. But I already upvoted even before your edit :-)

Comment: @Gallifreyan I'd say it's just a word play. One can speculate that Jah's switching from old school music to something new and experimental, and it can look like a betrayal of his roots. It's just my guess, there can be plenty of other interpretations. If you are interseted in Russian culture we have a [nice meme](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) about that.

Comment: +1 for excellent answer. However, it would be better if tou added that BG was very explicitly [extremely into Rastafarianism](http://www.guelman.ru/music/critics/greb.htm) and Bob Marley (and MASs, duh); which would also address @Randal'Thor's concern.

Comment: @Shokhet - it most certainly is. Everyone (from BG's example) was into Reggae.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - one kinda-reference :) http://www.aquarium.ru/misc/history/history052.html

Comment: @Randal'Thor another reference: "Поскольку в этот период нам удалось сочинить несколько реггей-номеров, мы приняли естественное решение - записывать не электрическую программу тбилисского фестиваля, а новые песни: "Рутман", "Джа даст нам все", "Река". В итоге мы стали записываться сами, без профессионалов Губермана и Фагота. Записываться, как Бог на душу положит."  (from BG himself: http://www.ytime.com.ua/ru/55/1187/0/)

Comment: Also, while uncited, Russian Wiki entry for Blue album: "Во время записи альбома члены группы были увлечены регги и растафарианством, результатом чего стало наличие на «Синем альбоме» нескольких песен регги на соответствующую тематику: «Рутман», «Единственный дом (Джа даст нам всё)» ..."